# Problems on pass user specifications to dplyr within Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, dplyr

I'm writing a new Shiny app, and I would like to use dplyr commands for data manipulation. I want Shiny to print some graphs that takes as input some aggregate data. For example, one user may want to see the graph mean vs simi.mean with week fixed at 0, while another will want to see mean vs simi.mean with rel fixed at 1.

I have this for ui.R:

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(' '),
  sidebarPanel(
selectInput('zcol', 'Variable to be fixed',  names(taxi.agg[,-c(1,4,5,7,8,9,10,11)])),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.zcol == 'week'",
                 selectInput("levels", "Levels",c(0,1),selected = 1
                 )),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.zcol == 'tollfree'",
                 selectInput("levels", "Levels",c(0,1),selected = 1
                 )),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.zcol == 'rel'",
                 selectInput("levels", "Levels",c(1,4),selected = 1
                 )),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.zcol == 'source'",
                 selectInput("levels", "Levels",c(1,2),selected = 1
                 )),
conditionalPanel(condition = "input.zcol == 'hour'",
                 sliderInput("levels", "Levels",value = 18,
                             min = 0, 
                             max = 23
                 ))
  ),
  mainPanel(
plotOutput('plot1')
  )
))
```

and this for server.R:

```
taxi.agg <- read.delim("taxi", header=T,colClasses =c(rep("factor",7),rep("numeric",5),rep("factor",2)) )


shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  output$selectedData <- renderTable({ 
data_stats <- eval(substitute(taxi.agg %>%  group_by(simi.mean,col) %>% summarise(mean = mean(prop.conv)) %>% 
                                  filter(col==lvl) %>% select(simi.mean,mean), 
                                list(col=as.symbol(input$zcol),
                                     lvl=as.symbol(input$levels))))
  })

  output$plot1 <- renderPlot({
 plot(selectedData())
  })

})
```

Outside of Shiny, the command:

```
plot(data_stats)
```

gives the answer that I want. But in Shiny I get:

> Error in plot(selectedData()) : could not find function "selectedData"

I think I might be doing something wrong on passing the parameters at the dplyr constructed table.
Any ideas? Thanks for the help!

Comment: You have assigned `selecteData` to an output. Instead try `selectedData<-reactive({ eval(substitute(taxi.agg %>% ... )}`

Comment: Hi @JohnPaul thanks for the quick response. Now I get `Error in lapply(obj, function(val) { : object 'taxi.agg' not found` . But if I read the dataset outside Shiny, everything works fine.

Comment: So you are reading `taxi.agg` in your `server.r` file, but you then try to use it in `ui.r` so the ui is confused. The simplest way to fix this to make a new file `global.r` and read in `taxi.agg` there, and it will be available to both the server and the ui.

Comment: Just solve it. I create a global.R file to do the reading of the data instead of doing so in a function and the reactive solution now works. Thanks!